# create iso file from installed Linux mint in hdd?

Tags: linux

can I create an iso image of Linux mint, which I have already installed  in my hard disk.
I already used brasero but I don't know what files are to be copied to the directory 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this porpose you can use ReLinux.

Relinux is a fork of the recently discontinued Remastersys.
Relinux create a DVD image of your machine with the exact same software included on the disk.

this is a nice HowTo:
https://www.howtoforge.com/creating-your-own-distributable-ubuntu-dvd-relinux